# How do I get my corner ribbon to render properly?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a corner ribbon that appears
[image: like this] but as of now, mine: [image: goes way over the parent div]. My CSS for the ribbon is

```
.flag {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* top left corner */
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}
```

How can I get my corner ribbon to look as desired? I have a code pen link [here](https://codepen.io/andrewt200/pen/ExNWXXB)

Comment: if you could share it as a working demo using jsfiddle / codepen it would be helpful

Comment: either way you have wrap the flag div with another element and give that overflow:hidden; style

Comment: hi @PrinjuKoshyVaidyan I've added a codepen link

Comment: updated answer..

Answer (score 0):

in styles

```
      .annual{
      overflow: hidden;
      }
     .annual  .flag{
        left: -36%;
        text-align: center;
        top: 26px;
      }
```